# Most common freerolling situations in holdem?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Player1 K♣T♣

Player2 K♥T♥

Board is A♣ Q♦ J♥ 4♣

This one is most common, what are the few others(most common)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'd like to know what you or others might gain from having this question answered. What use would it be?

Answer (score 3):

Freerolling implies having an exact same hand made as your opponent plus drawing to a better hand *that your opponent cannot make*. "Most common" simply means that some situations would have a higher statistical probablility than the others.

IMO the term can only be applied during a showdown or in a later analysis i.e. only after you have seen the opponent's cards. Knowing statistically most common situations will not improve your game - when you have a made straight and a flush draw, the opponent could be on a higher flush draw even without the straight etc. etc.; just play the odds as you normally would.

Comment: You can absolutely know that you are freerolling, if you have the nuts and a draw to better nuts. That said, I agree that it's not relevant to your play in hold'em. It can be in Omaha.

Comment: @JeffreyBlake: What about if you have a nut straight, are drawing to a nut flush but your opponent has three-of-a-kind and is drawing to full house or quads? Regardless of still having favourable odds, I don't believe this situation qualifies to be called a freeroll. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, that would not qualify as freerolling because your opponent has good outs to beat you as well. I think truely meaningful freerolling situations happen the most in split pot games.

Comment: @JeffreyBlake: that's exactly my thinking. And, since you can't confidently know if your opponent is drawing to such a hand, you can't know you're freerolling for a fact. As I speculated in the answer above, the term "free-rolling" could only be applied after the hands have been revealed, (somewhat similar to commenting on someone "drawing dead" - you can't know you're drawing dead until you see the opponent's cards... otherwise you wouldn't call would you? :)