# What does 'freerolling' mean?

Tags: terminology

I was reading the [most common freerolling situations in holdem](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/611/most-common-freerolling-situations-in-holdem), but I have no idea what is being asked. What is **Freerolling**?

Google wasn't any help (hit too many free rolls vs. freerolling), and we didn't have any answers here that I found.

Comment: I would like to recommend this Wikipedia glossary for future reference which covers many different poker terms, including freerolling: [Glossary of poker terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_poker_terms).

Comment: In addition to a freeroll, there is also a *reverse freeroll*, in which there is limited or no upside to a particular gamble.  Consider a situation in which you have bottom straight on a 4 flush board.  If you bet and get action, there is often little chance your hand will win the whole pot, and very often you will lose the whole pot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a term used to describe a situation in which there is no more downside risk involved for one or more active participants, only upside positive outcomes can be realized. A "shot to nothing" is a similar expression.

In the example from the question you link to, both players currently have the best hand, an Ace-high straight, yet only one player also has a flush draw. That player is *freerolling* as he can't lose (no downside risk) but can still beat his opponent by improving to a flush (upside).

In the context of poker, a freeroll is an opportunity to play with no cost, yet there are still potential rewards. Hence, any similar situation could be thought of as a chance at *freerolling*.

Answer (score 0):

Is where a player cant lose a hand against his opponent, the worst scenario is a chop, for example

3d 8d Qs on the flop

and the freerolling player has Qd 10d and his opponent Qh 10h
whatever card it comes freerolling player will chop or win with any diamond